# getting "SyntaxError: missing : after property id " while setting up source for jquery auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm new new to jQuery so I don't know what's wrong with this.I would like to set up an array for the source for the autocomplete ui and set into a varaiable so I could use it later. I would like to compare the Items in the array to what is in the text box when the users closes the option menu. If the user's input matches the Items in the array then the input should be appended to the body. If it doesnt match, it shouldn't be appended. It looks like I am having problems creating the array. because I have a syntax error on that line.
Here's the code:

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  var arr = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
    source : arr,
  close: function(){
    var val = $('input#autocomplete').val()
    if ($.inArray(val,arr) > -1) {
    $('body').append(val);
}


}
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/A4eH8/1/)

Comment: Click "Tidy Up" then "JSHint" in your fiddle, finally open browser console, problem is immediately visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't allow placing a `var` declaration directly within an `Object` literal  -- `{...}`.

You just need to separate them into individual statements:

```
var arr = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ];

$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: arr,
    close: function(){
        var val = $('input#autocomplete').val()
        if ($.inArray(val,arr) > -1) {
            $('body').append(val);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is just wrong. Variable initializations are done with `=`, not `:`.

```
var arr = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ],
    source  = arr,
  close = function(){
    var val = $('input#autocomplete').val();
    if ($.inArray(val,arr) > -1) {
       $('body').append(val);
    };
  };
```